# Why does Gerrit compares a newly added file with a renamed file?

Tags: git, gerrit

I renamed a file `ivim_uc5.xml` to `ivim_uc5_z1.xml`. Then I created 9 new files with the name `ivim_uc5_z2.xml ivim_uc5_z3.xml` and so on. After pushing the `Gerrit` shows like this:

[image]

Why is it comparing the new files with a renamed file and how do I avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "C" character on Gerrit UI indicates that you have copied the ivim_uc5_Z*.xml files from the ivim_uc5.xml one.

See here:

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html#files

There's no way to change this behaviour but IMHO this is a very useful information and I can't see any issue with this.